# I'm able to sort but unable to drag particular value

Tags: jquery, html

I'm able to sort the values and also able to drag values, i.e., all contents inside `ul` but unable to drag a particular value of, i.e., `li`. I want to drag and drop values one by one to "Add my stories here".

You can check my code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/coolanuj/7683X/6/).

Comment: Where do you want to drop them to? Sorting is technically drag and drop, its just in the same container.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: Kindly check my code and run it . There are three values of li and they are sortable means i can drag and drop anywhere in the same div But what i want that i can drag my any value of li into another div i.e into the "Add your stories" container.

@KonstantinD-Infragistics : kindly run my code and check it in jsfidddle

Comment: @Asad : kindly run my code and check it in jsfidddle .

Comment: please check my updated code http://jsfiddle.net/coolanuj/7683X/7/

Comment: Is there a reason for the `accept` option for `droppable`? Removing it fixes the issue for me.

Comment: @pimvdb  :
    Thanx for replying . But its not working for me . Any more possible solution .